# Contact list not accessing all contacts phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I created a project in phonegap in appery.io framework. It is not cordova based project but I installed cordova library manually. I am fetching contacts list using Jquery but it is fetching only device contacts list not the sim contacts list. If i want to install cordova contacts plugin using commands then it is showing current directory is not a cordova based project. if anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, if you created an app in Appery.io, it comes bundled with Apache Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this to save all contacts in sdcard and display. (default Cordova contacts and file plugin)

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

   function deviceReady() {

 navigator.contacts.find(["*"], function(contacts) {

  //alert("contacts.length = " + contacts.length);

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("contacts.json", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.onwriteend = function(){
              // Success Contacts saved to sdcard as a contacts.json file
              // Now get and read the json file 

var path = fileSystem.root.getFile("contacts.json", {create:false},gotFileEntry, fail);

       // jquery

  $.getJSON(path, function (data) {

user = data;
$.each(user, function (index, user) {
    var all_item = '<p id="'+user.id+'">'+user.displayName+'</p>';
    $('#allcontacts').append(all_item);
});
   });
            };
                  writer.write(JSON.stringify(contacts));

        }, onError);

    }, onError);

}, onError);

    }, onError,{"multiple": true});}  
    function onError(){
        alert("Error"); 
             }
```