# How to get sim card contacts in ionic framework or cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get All contact from Phone and Sim card in ionic frame work.I got all contact from Phone but not from SIM

I tried [Link for NGCORDOVA CONTACTS](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/)

but from this not able to get SIM contacts 
I tried to get sim info by [SIM INFO PLUGIN](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sim)

from this got all info but not sim contacts.
what to do please help.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342604/contact-list-not-accessing-all-contacts-phonegap/33400964#33400964][1]

Answer (score 2):

Using following plugin [DeviceInformation plugin](https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin).
It is used to get the following information from your device and sim.

1. Your unique Device ID
2. Phone Number (if it is stored in your SIM card)
3. Country ISO of your phone network provider
4. Name of your network provider
5. Your SIM Card Serial number
6. Country ISO of your SIMcard
7. Name of your SIM card mobile operator
8. E-mail/Phone number used by apps listed in your Settings > Accounts & Sync list

```js
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(function(result) {
        console.log("result = " + result);
    }, function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```