# How to get mobile details and sim details using ionic 3 and cordova for Android

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new in Ionic . Please guide me how to get mobile details and sim details using ionic 3 and cordova for Android. your help is appreciated in advance

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get sim card contacts in ionic framework or cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543269/how-to-get-sim-card-contacts-in-ionic-framework-or-cordova)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Device native plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/).

> Access information about the underlying device and platform.

[**Article about it.**](http://pointdeveloper.com/get-device-information-ionic-3/)

If you need to get the details of `Sim` then you can use [**Sim native plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/).

> Gets info from the Sim card like the carrier name, mcc, mnc and
>   country code and other system dependent info.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample working code. It will be a great help.